# how to integrate payment gateway in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, payment-gateway, phonegap-build

I have integrated instamojo payment gateway in an app. Everything is fine. However, after the payment is successfull, I want to return the user to my app. The payment stuff is happening in webview and the response page is set to one of my server page that is(pay.php) which is over the server. The app is going to the pay.php after successful transaction. Now from there I want to return to my mobile app pages. I have tried to open a link in external browser, so that in that link i can set a href value to : "myapp://" and auto run the url, so that it returns to my app. I am unable to achieve to open the link in an external browser from "pay.php" page which is over server end

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To close a inAppBrowser after all the payment functions are done, you need to add this code at the end so that it closes your inAppBrowser and you can return to your app.

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
        if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
            ref.close();
        }
    )
};
```